# What does 'RuntimeError: PyFunctionConstraint: Output must be of scalar type AutoDiffXd, but unable to infer scalar type.' mean?

Tags: drake

When attempting to solve my mathematical program, drake produces the RuntimeError: `PyFunctionConstraint: Output must be of scalar type AutoDiffXd, but unable to infer scalar type.`

The constraint responsible for the error is as follows:

```
def non_penetration_constraint(q):
    plant_ad.SetPositions(context_ad, q)
    Distances = np.zeros(6, dtype=q.dtype)
    i = 0
    for name in Claw_name:
        g_ids = body_geometries[name]
        assert(len(g_ids) == 1)
        Distances[i] = query_object.ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints(
            Worldbody_id, g_ids[0]).distance
        i += 1

    return Distances
```

Called with:

```
for n in range(N-1):
    # Non penetration constraint
    prog.AddConstraint(non_penetration_constraint,
                       lb = [0] * nf,
                       ub = [0] * nf,
                       vars = (q[:, n]))
```

Has anybody had a similar issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your `query_object` (and perhaps other values) are not from the autodiff version of your plant/scene_graph.

Constraints implemented like this can potentially be called with q[0] either a type float or type AutoDiffXd. See the "writing custom evaluator" section of [this Drake tutorial](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/tutorials/mathematical_program_multibody_plant.ipynb). In your case, the return value from your constraint is coming out of the `query_object`, which is not impacted directly by the `plant_ad.SetPositions` call (which seems suspicious).  You'll want to make sure the query_object is generated from the autodiff scene_graph, and presumably *after* you set the positions to your constraint value.